# Suggested edit that only changes tags, also shows the title as removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits

I have a doubt that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1400003) is real:

[image: Title marked as removed]

Either the display is buggy or the title validation is buggy. Or my monitor is *really* buggy. Or my brain, but you can't fix that.

---

#### Update

The edit was eventually approved, and appears to contain no real title change. This gets the Markdown diff into trouble, then...

Comment: I have noticed several variations of this; it seems title changes don't work quite as expected.

Comment: I vote for "all of the above". But yeah, looks like the diff forgot about retagging.

Comment: And 2 out of 4 did reject this edit -- like I would, unless I doubted the display. So, this surely will make reviewers make the wrong decision. Sounds like an urgent bug to me.

Comment: (As an aside, for image `alt` text fun, please use `title` instead? We *do* have people using screen readers on these sites. The many default "enter image description here" `alt` texts are probably already annoying for them, but I *assume* using `title` can be handled better by a good screen reader. Cheers.)

Comment: is tagged as [meta-tag:status-completed], but I'm seeing lost of weirdness in the Suggested Edit diffs this evening.... either titles showing as removed as the OP mention, or no diff showing for Title-only changes.  Was this fix actually deployed?

Comment: @psubsee2003: See comments on balpha's answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I didn't see those comments when I started typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spot the mistake :)

```
public bool HasTitleEdits { get { return SuggestedEdit.HasTagEdits; } }
```

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: It seems like now, proposed edits that only change the title show no diffs at all. Before the fix, I hope.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't rolled out yet. I'll do that now; should be correct in a few minutes.

Comment: Lulz. Also interesting to get a glimpse into how the highlighting is done -- when `HasTitleEdits` is `true`, it does a diff and falls back on just highlighting everything if it can't find a localised change?

Comment: As an aside, is there perhaps a "status-sort-of-completed" tag for fixes that have been committed but not yet deployed?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Re your first question -- a suggested edit that doesn't change the title doesn't store the title at all. Thus when creating a diff because of an incorrect `HasTitleEdits`, it creates a diff between the original title and an empty one, which is what you saw. Re your second question -- no.

Comment: Good answers :)